# FRAGMENT ACCESS in Ether.js library

Tags: web3js, wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp, ethers.js

As I read [Uniswap front end code](https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-interface/blob/main/src/state/multicall/hooks.ts#L167), I see that they use `contract.interface.getFunction` to get the function fragment rather than use `contract.methodName` to trigger the function of the contract

I don't know what the purpose of using a function fragment or fragment in general in [ethers.js](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/search/?search=Fragment) is.

Answer (score 1):

Fragments are basically the JSON ABI which is output from Solidity Compiler ([relevant docs link](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/abi/fragments/)). You can encode input data by also passing the fragments using an ethers.js [AbiCoder](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/abi/coder/#AbiCoder-encode).

As far I'm seeing, they are optimising their queries with [multicall](https://github.com/makerdao/multicall), so they are not doing simply `contract.methodName`, since that would trigger separate RPC request. This is used to save on the requests bill in Infura or Alchemy.

But in ethers.js, a multicall provider is in the works, which would enable you to acheive the same without the complex code, i.e. if you do multiple `contract.viewOrPureMethod` calls within `10ms`, the provider will send them under a multicall instead of individual calls.